# Ionic 2 Modal make 50% of the width

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic2

I have a page in my ionic application that on button click opens a Modal Page. Currently, I have override the variable.scss to the code below to make the model cover the 100% of the page.

```
//for Modals
$modal-inset-height-large: 100%;
$modal-inset-height-small: $modal-inset-height-large;
$modal-inset-width: 100%;
```

However, this applies for all my models in my application. I want to use some models in other pages that use the 50% of the width and around 80% of the height. How can I customize my controls?

Comment: Have you tried resizing the ion-content of your modal page ?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

You can not change a particular modal height or width.
Now, I will describe an solution which I use to resize my modal.

1. Ensured that all modal height and width should be 100%. As ionic
   resize modal for large screen devices. That's why I added below code
   in `app.scss`.

```css
modal-wrapper {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

@media not all and (min-height: 600px) and (min-width: 768px) {
  ion-modal ion-backdrop {
    visibility: hidden;
  }
}

@media only screen and (min-height: 0px) and (min-width: 0px) {
  .modal-wrapper {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
  }
}
```

2. Now In ion-content we make two div and the background of ion-content should be transparent (see `main-view` css class). Now, One div is used for background of the modal, this will use as backdrop (see `overlay` css class). Another div should be used for the content, we will resize this div (see `modal-content` css class).In example I resize the height to 50%. Sample html ans css code is given below,

```css
page-about {
  .main-view{
    background: transparent;
  }
  .overlay {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    z-index: 1;
    opacity: .5;
    background-color: #333;
  }
  .modal_content {
    position: absolute;
    top: calc(50% - (50%/2));
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 50%;
    padding: 10px;
    z-index: 100;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 10px;
    color: #333;
    background: #e8e8e8;
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #fff 0%, #e8e8e8 100%);
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #fff 0%, #e8e8e8 100%);
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #fff 0%, #e8e8e8 100%);
    border-radius: 5px;
    box-shadow: 0 2px 3px rgba(51, 51, 51, .35);
    box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    overflow: hidden;
  }
}
```

```html
<ion-content class="main-view">
  <div class="overlay" (click)="dismiss()"></div>
  <div class="modal_content">
    <h2>Welcome to Ionic!</h2>
    <p>
      This starter project comes with simple tabs-based layout for apps that are going to primarily use a Tabbed UI.
    </p>
    <p>
      Take a look at the <code>src/pages/</code> directory to add or change tabs, update any existing page or create new
      pages.
    </p>
  </div>
</ion-content>
```

Here is a screen shot of the modal,

[image]

**If you want modal content should scroll then replace `<div class="modal_content">` with `<ion-scroll class="modal_content" scrollY="true">` as told by [Missak Boyajian](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4592546/missak-boyajian) in [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43606619/ionic-2-modal-make-50-of-the-width/43609883?noredirect=1#comment74298647_43609883)**

**For Ionic3 you need to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43606619/ionic-2-modal-make-50-of-the-width/43609883#comment81291867_43609883) comment from [Alston Sahyun Kim](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5404012/alston-sahyun-kim).**

```
this is an excellent answer, just one thing from ionic3, .main-view{ background: transparent; } should be .content{ background: transparent; }
```

**All the code is taken from [here](https://github.com/math10/ResizeModal-Ionic). I think [this project](https://github.com/math10/ResizeModal-Ionic) repo will help you.**

Comment: WOW. Thanks it worked. one small thing. My modal is a bit longer and the scrolling is not working. Can that be done ?

Comment: I didn't do this yet.

Comment: Ok I added <ion-scroll scrollY="true"> it worked. Thanks

Comment: Thanks. I added <ion-scroll scrollY="true"> in github repo.

Comment: How to make height dynamic, depending upon the content size??

Comment: You can change particular modal height and width by assigning css to selectors.

Comment: This answer is a God send! Thanks a lot @Math10. Cheers.

Comment: this is an excellent answer, just one thing from ionic3,
.main-view{
    background: transparent;
  }
should be
.content{
    background: transparent;
  }

Comment: Just to complete @MuneemHabib answer. You can change particular modal height/width assigning a css class when you create with i.e: let modal = this.modalCtrl.create(AddNoteModalPage, null, {cssClass: 'my-modal'}); and then wrap your css rules at app.scss: .my-modal{ modal-wrapper {...} ... }

Comment: By hiding the backdrop you loose some embedded functionality. I mean you cannot dismiss the modal when you click on the backdrop.

Comment: Please, there is an error when someone click the transparent background.

_co.dismiss is not a function

Do you have any idea how we can solve this, thanks

Comment: I got the above issue solved by adding a dismiss() method within my modal component,

Thanks

Comment: I used same dummy code and it is not working like shared image ,:(*

Comment: @Anuj Are you using ionic 2 or ionic 3? You need to change some portion (you can find them in comments) for ionic 3.

Comment: I am using ionic 3 . checking comment

Comment: In Ionic 5 how to implement this?

Answer (score 2):

I tried before but had not found a generic way to make modals behave the way as I desired.

So I strugled a bit and achieved **responsive modals** and other kinds of modals with the following global scss:

```scss
ion-modal {
    &.my-modal-inner {
        display: flex;
        align-items: center;
        justify-content: center;

        ion-backdrop {
            visibility: visible;
        }

        .modal-wrapper {
            display: flex;
            align-items: flex-start;
            justify-content: center;
            overflow: auto;
            width: auto;
            height: auto;
            left: auto;
            top: auto;
            contain: content;

            max-width: 70%;
            max-height: 70%;

            border-radius: 2px;
            box-shadow: 0 28px 48px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);

            > .ion-page {
                position: relative;
                display: block;
                width: auto;
                height: auto;
                contain: content;
                box-shadow: 0 28px 48px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
            }
        }

        &.my-stretch {
            .modal-wrapper {
                overflow: hidden;
                width: 100%;
                height: 100%;

                > .ion-page {
                    width: 100%;
                    height: 100%;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    &.my-fullscreen {
        .modal-wrapper {
            position: absolute;
            display: block;
            top: 0;
            left: 0;
            width: 100%;
            height: 100%;
        }
    }   
}
```

You can have **responsive modals** that will have the size of the inner content using `cssClass: 'my-modal-inner'`:

[image]

The modal will occupy at maximum 70% of the width and height (like defined in the above css) **when the content surpasses the limit**:

[image]

If the content of the modal **is supposed to occupy all the container element** (like a page or a component with `ion-content`), it will not work well with the above case because the modal supposes that the container should have the size of its children, causing a possibly **undesired behaviour** (the modal will be very small, more than it should):

[image]

Instead, you can define the modal **to occupy its maximum size** with `cssClass: 'my-modal-inner my-stretch'`:

[image]

If you want the modal to be **full screen**, even in a large desktop browser, you can use `cssClass: 'my-fullscreen'`:

[image]

**Notes:**

1. You can **change the prefix** `my-` with any other prefix of your choice (or no prefix).
2. You can **change the maximum width and height** of the modal in the above css, as you seem fit (I defined both as 70%, **in your case it would be 50% and 80% for the width and height, respectively**).
3. The above screenshots were taken in a desktop browser, but the modal changes also work in a mobile/native app with Ionic (I tested in Android, and it should work in iOS too).

**Update (2018-07-30)**

About the HTML codes for the modal:

**1)** Responsive modal that will be as large or as small as the inner content (a single `div` or a hierarchy of `divs`, `spans` and other block and inline elements should do):

```html
<div class="main">
    <div class="img-container">
        <img src="assets/img/main/icon.png" [alt]="APP_NAME">
    </div>
    <div class="info-container">
        <div class="app-name">{{ APP_NAME }}</div>
        <div class="app-version">Version {{ APP_VERSION }}</div>
        <div class="app-year">@{{ INITIAL_YEAR }}-{{ CURRENT_YEAR }} {{ APP_NAME }}</div>
        <div class="app-rights">All rights reserved</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**2)** Modal will occupies its maximum size (use class `my-stretch`). In this case, any ionic page will do:

```html
<ion-header>
    <ion-navbar>
        <ion-title>My Title</ion-title>
    </ion-navbar>
</ion-header>
<ion-content>
    <p> My content </p>
</ion-content>
```

Comment: @SaravananNandhan I updated my answer with HTML examples.

Comment: How to implement this in ionic5?

Comment: @Arj1411 I'm not using ionic5 so I think I can not help you with that :/