# how to change the height and width of an modal in ionic 3

Tags: angular, sass, ionic2, ionic3

I'm expecting a model to be used as an alert.

here is what I have tried

```
presentModal() {
    const myModelOpts: ModalOptions = {
      // showBackdrop: false,
      enableBackdropDismiss: false
    }
    const myData = {
      pageName: "home"
    }
    let modal = this.modalCtrl.create(ModelPage, { data: myData}, myModelOpts);
    modal.present();
  }
```

I am getting the model page but I am not able to radius the height and width of my model and show backdrop.

I also tried applying

```
$modal-inset-min-width:500px
```

in my variable.scss and app.scss but it is not working

how can I make use of the this `$modal-inset-min-width` or is there any other way to achieve this

this is my my image without any device mode

[image: img]

this my image with mobile device mode

[image: img]

i want the first image type in the mobile device mode

Comment: Do you want to change the height and width of a particular modal or all modal in your application?

Comment: particular modal i want to change @Math10

Comment: Could you please see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43606619/ionic-2-modal-make-50-of-the-width/43609883#43609883) answer? I think you need this solution.

Comment: please check my updated question @Math10

Comment: Should I assume that you always want a same percent of width and height? (let's assume width = 70% and height = 80%)

Comment: yes something like that

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/150051/discussion-between-mohan-gopi-and-math10).

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the docs for [Modal Controller](https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/components/modal/ModalController/), they also elude to cssClass in Advanced.
That wasn't exactly illuminating..
So I looked at the source for the [class](https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic/blob/master/src/components/modal/modal.ts)
It passes in opts: [ModalOptions](https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic/blob/master/src/components/modal/modal-options.ts) = {} ..
The source shows it's an interface so you should be able to do  `cssClass?: string;`.
So you could try creating your own CSS Style and linking that in your `myModelOpts` variable..

Comment: in the same modal controller api we some something like `Sass Variables` and given some options where we can change globally or create an sass file and import into our particular page

Answer (score 0):

1st see this [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43606619/ionic-2-modal-make-50-of-the-width/43609883#43609883).

Now you need to change the `modal_content` css with you expected width and height. Change YOUE_EXPECTED_HEIGHT and YOUE_EXPECTED_WIDTH with your expected height and width percent.

```css
page-about {
  .main-view{
    background: transparent;
  }
  .overlay {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    z-index: 1;
    opacity: .5;
    background-color: #333;
  }
  .modal_content {
    position: absolute;
    top: calc(50% - (YOUE_EXPECTED_HEIGHT/2));
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    width: YOUE_EXPECTED_WIDTH;
    height: YOUE_EXPECTED_HEIGHT;
    padding: 10px;
    z-index: 100;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 10px;
    color: #333;
    background: #e8e8e8;
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #fff 0%, #e8e8e8 100%);
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #fff 0%, #e8e8e8 100%);
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #fff 0%, #e8e8e8 100%);
    border-radius: 5px;
    box-shadow: 0 2px 3px rgba(51, 51, 51, .35);
    box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    overflow: hidden;
  }
}
```