# Can I add a search bar in a <ion-select> tag?

Tags: html, ionic-framework

I made a `<ion-select>` tag to choose some elements as below. In case I have too many elements to show on here, I want to add a search bar in the tag.

[image]

Is it possible to do this? Adding `<ion-toolbar>` in `<ion-select>` doesn't get this solved...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, but you can create a new page, and add both `ion-select` and `ion-search` there. Then show this page instead of your original `ion-select`.

Comment: Just FYI, if you don't like your modal take entire screen, there are ways to show a new page as a modal that takes 50% of the screen. Here is an example solution (You can Google for more): https://stackoverflow.com/a/43609883/1383356